# How do I make Pylint command run in PyCharm (Python)

Tags: python, pycharm, chalice

I have already installed pylint, and when I  try to run:

```
python3 -m pylint app.py chalicelib tests
```

I receive this error:

> /usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pylint

Here is what my PATH is:

```
➜  ~ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
➜  ~ which python
python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: The question is where you did install the package. There can be multiple interpreters on your machine including virtual environments.

Comment: @PavelKarateev local machine

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. The problem is you can have e.g. a virtualenv created locally by PyCharm, and `pylint` can be installed there instead of a system `/usr/local/bin/python3`. This way `python3 -m pylint` will give you and error, as it indeed doesn't have the package installed. I wonder where did you run `pip install pylint`, was it the system terminal? PyCharm built-in terminal? Or maybe PyCharm UI for package management?

Comment: yes PyCharm built terminal

Comment: Which interpreter do you have selected in "Settings | Project | Project Interpreter" in PyCharm?